# Group by statement cannot be translated to SQL

Tags: c#, group-by, max, ef-core-3.1, entity-framework-core-3.1

Is there a way in EF Core 3.1 to get a group by statement like the below to work?

```
 .GroupBy(x => x.Id, (id, item) =>
          new 
          {
              Id = id,
              LastDate = item.Max(z => z.Date)
          })
```

Id being a `uniqueidentifier` and Date being a `datetime2(7)`

This currently cannot be translated to SQL with the error

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Delivery>
    .GroupBy(
        source: p => p.Id, 
        keySelector: p => p, 
        elementSelector: (x, y) => new { 
            Id = x, 
            LastDate = y
                .Max(z => z.Date)
         })' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().
```

Comment: The query you've posted works. Please make sure you post reproducible example.

Comment: I got it. Made a stupid mistake. The id column in the entity didn't exist in the table.